# TestComplete gives Error Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

Tags: jscript, testcomplete

Please find below code as it gives error 'object requred' on
If (aqString["ToUpper"](strCellValue) == aqString["ToUpper"](StrVal)) line.

```
function tableClick(){

  ObjTable = mGetObject(sGlobalPageURL,"ObjectType,Name","Table,Table*list_product_group_table*")
  intRows =  ObjTable.RowCount
  strCellValue = "TAA - Test Automation Account"

  for (i = 1; i < intRows; i++) { 
    StrVal = ObjTable.Cell(i,0).innerText
     If (aqString["ToUpper"](strCellValue) == aqString["ToUpper"](StrVal))
     {
      ObjTable.Cell(i,3).click()
      break; 
     }
   }  
}
```

Comment: FYI: There's a shorter code for this comparison: `if (aqString["Compare"](strCellValue, StrVal, true) == 0)`

Answer (score 0):

The JScript language does not have the **If** keyword (first I capitalized). Use small letters for keywords:

```
 if (aqString["ToUpper"](strCellValue) == aqString["ToUpper"](StrVal))
```